# How does (Gnome) Desktop Notification work?

Tags: c++, gtk, desktop, gnome

For example
[image: gnome chat]

Or the Filezilla Notification "Upload complete!".

How can i use it in my C++ Application? I have searched at developer.gnome.org and found [this](https://developer.gnome.org/notification-spec/) and [this](http://standards.freedesktop.org/startup-notification-spec/startup-notification-latest.txt) but they were not very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the notification in the screenshot is a chat notification, and it's handled by GNOME Shell directly; chat notifications cannot be implemented outside of the Shell, so you'll either need to patch GNOME Shell or write a Shell extension.

generic notifications (transient or permanent) can be sent from your application by using the `libnotify` API: https://git.gnome.org/browse/libnotify

you can also send notifications using the console, through the `notify-send` command line utility (which is usually shipped as part of the libnotify package).